# How to union two LINQ queries (WhereSelectEnumerableIterator) error

Tags: vb.net, linq, entity-framework

I am trying to build aKendo bar chart. I need the number of tickets opened, and tickets closed. I need that result grouped by month. Here is my LINQ

```
Dim openTickets = (From t In queue _
                   Where _
                   (t.CreateDate.Year = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year)
                   Group t By _
                   ID = CType(t.CreateDate.Month, Integer), _
                   Month = CType(t.CreateDate.ToString("MMMM"), String) _
                   Into g = Group _
                   Select New With _
                   {.Month = Month.Substring(0, 3), .Opened = g.Where(Function(t) t.CreateDate.Month = ID).Count(Function(t) t.Id)})

Dim closedTickets = (From t In queue _
                   Where _
                   (t.CloseDate.Year = Convert.ToDateTime(DateTime.Now).Year)
                   Group t By _
                   ID = CType(t.CloseDate.Month, Integer), _
                   Month = CType(t.CloseDate.ToString("MMMM"), String) _
                   Into g = Group _
                   Select New With _
                   {.Month = Month.Substring(0, 3), .Closed = g.Where(Function(t) t.CloseDate.Month = ID).Count(Function(t) t.Id)})

Dim ticketCount = openTickets.Union(closedTickets)
```

When I try this, I get "WhereSelectEnumerableIterator". If I change the second query so that the name is ".Opened" and not ".Closed" it works, but then I do not know my count for "closed".

Ultimately I am trying to get an output of an array to supply the chart... similar to this:

```
[{"Month":"Apr","Opened":138,"Closed":150}

INSTEAD OF

[{"Month":"Apr","Opened":138,"Closed":0},{"Month":"Apr","Opened":0,"Closed":150}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to use a `Join` statement to merge the two and keep the values distinct.  Something like this:

```
Dim tickets = From open In openTickets _
              Join closed In closedTickets _
              On open.Month Equals closed.Month _
              Select New With _
              {.Month = open.Month, .Opened = open.Opened, .Closed = closed.Closed}
```

Comment: You da man! That worked! Also I see what you are doing so I feel like I learned something as well.